# 'Emulator can not be opened because of a problem' AVD not working in Android Studio on Mac Yosemite

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device, osx-yosemite

I have created a few virtual devices in Android Studio, but I'm not able to run any. Here's my error msg:
[image]

Here's some things I've tried:

1. Creating a NEXUS 4 AVD (to be able to choose 'Software-GLES 2.0' from 'Emulated performance graphics' in the AVD manager.)
2. Uninstall, then reinstall the Intel x86 HAXM installer.

I will be upgrading my mid-2012 MacBook Pro's OS to Catalina soon, but for now I have to run Yosemite which is supposed to be supported by Android Studio 3.6.1.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I restarted Android Studio and create a new device in AVD MANAGER then I have increased the RAM size of emulator and it works nicely.

Comment: I increased the RAM size of the emulator, using this method : http://lifeofcoding.com/2015/01/19/How-to-increase-Android-studio-memory-limit-in-Mac/ . I restarted my Mac and created a new AVD, another Nexus 4 with 'Emulated performance graphics' set to 'Software'. Still no luck, same ERROR msgs :-/

Answer (score 0):

An OS upgrade to Catalina did the trick, though the devices are quite slow to load. I managed to run a NEXUS 4 AVD (left it on 'Auto' for the 'Emulated performance graphics' option in the AVD manager.)